# Background smooth geometry vs background edge geometry

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry

In this [note, page 8 and page 9](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7451), the Kähler–Einstein edge equation is written first in (3.7) in terms of a model edge metric and in (3.11) in terms of a smooth Kähler metric. What is the distinction between the two? Is any one of them better than the other?

Comment: It's the same equation but in the second case one has written the volume form of the edge metric as a singular density against a smooth volume form. Both formulations are useful, depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: It seems that in literature people always prove estimates in terms of the model edge metric rather than a fixed smooth metric. I fail to see why that is useful. Can you point me to any reference?